# Can you favorite a composer or works from an album in Apple Music Classical?

Tags: apple-music

Question about Apple Music classical, specifically about [this album and it’s composer:](https://classical.music.apple.com/us/album/476934698)

Can someone check if they can favorite  works from the linked album, or if they can favorite the composer of the album Min Xiao-fen, **in the Apple Music classical app**?

I cannot do so. I think perhaps the composer simply does not have the proper page or metadata.

- If someone else checks I will know whether is a problem just on my end or not.

[This is the album](https://classical.music.apple.com/us/album/476934698)

Comment: My testing suggests that making someone/thing a favourite is not in Apple Classical.  I can add Min Xiao-fen as a favourite in Apple Music.

Comment: By favorite I mean a star button.  For example, here (https://classical.music.apple.com/us/work/franz-liszt-1811-pp31) I can click star in top right to add this as a favorite work. Or here (https://classical.music.apple.com/us/artist/franz-liszt-1811) there is a star in the top right to add Franz Liszt as a favorite composer. But I can do any of those things for the album I asked about. You are right that there is a star I can click in the regular Apple Music app though. Interesting, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that “Min Xiao-fen” does not return any results for a composer or artist when searched in Apple Music classical.

It seems most or all artists from that label are as such, so perhaps it is a licensing or metadata problem .